# True but False in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to count if there is k-same consecutive number in my array 
For example if we want to check if there is is (k=)3 consecutive number the function will return :

```
[0,0,1,1,1,3,4,5,4,3] = true
[0,0,1,2,1,3,4,5,4,3] = false
```

I write

```html
def seq(a, n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if k <= 1:
        return 1
    return (a[0] == a[1] and seq(a[1:], n-1, k - 1)) or seq(a[1:], n - 1, k)`
```

But when i call *(seq(array, len(array), 3))* for **[2, 0, 0, 2, -4, -4, 0, 5, 0, 65, 66, 67]** 
its returning 1 instead of 0

Comment: is it because `K <= 1`?  maybe it should be simply `K < 1` (since, if `K == 1`, it would have met the first `if` case)

Comment: Well you have `0, 0` and `-4, -4`, both of which decrease your `k` by 1.

Comment: As an aside, why use 0 and 1 instead of proper boolean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are messing up what you have to have as your accumulator. What you should be accumulating is the last thing you saw and how many times you saw it. Where `a` is equal to the list we are checking, `n` is the number of times we have seen the element `e` and `k` is the number of consecutive elements we have to reach.

```
def seq(a, k):
    def seq_acc(a, n, e, k):
        if not a:
            return n == k
        if n == k:
            return True
        if e == a[0]:
            return seq_acc(a[1:], n+1, e, k)
        else:
            return seq_acc(a[1:], 1, a[0], k)
    if not a:
        return False
    else:
        return seq_acc(a[1:], 1, a[0], k)
```